# ubuntu-gnome on mac

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, mac, macbook, ubuntu-gnome

I would like to install [ubuntu-gnome 13.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/13.04/release/) which was released today on my macbook pro. However, unfortunately this version of ubuntu does not have and amd64+mac image.

Should I just install the regular amd64 release? Or is there no way to use ubuntu-gnome on mac?

EDIT:

Just installed the `amd64.iso` image of ubuntu-gnome 13.04 Raring. Works like a charm, it was easy to boot from a USB using rEFIT. Not only that, but all the hardware on my 2013 macbook pro was automatically detected, so I actually had internet during installation.

So it turns out the `+mac` series are really only needed if you run an older mac that won't be able to boot from the cd/usb install disk otherwise. However, it seems that this is not really needed for most newer macs, especially if you installed rEFIT. You can boot straight into grub-efi even with the regular `amd64` iso.

Great release!

Comment: Could you clarify: did you install the `...amd64+mac.iso` version or just the straight `...amd64.iso`? I'm also wondering if I need the mac specific version for my Macbook Air then customise to make it into Ubuntu Gnome.