# Why is there no +mac download for 32 bit systems or for GNOME?

Tags: system-installation, mac, 32-bit, ubuntu-gnome

When I was first toying with 64 bit Ubuntu I was led to try the +mac version of the installer and that solved some problems for me.

Now however, I

1. want to use GNOME; and
2. want the 32bit version.

Even for the standard Ubuntu, I couldn't find a +mac installer for 32 bit systems. For the GNOME flavour I couldn't find any +mac versions at all.

I've got a terribly slow internet connection so I want to avoid unnecessarily downloading many different Ubuntus to try and find out.

Do they not exist because they're not required anymore? If they do exist, where can I find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+mac` installers are for 64-bit only, since they deal with a problem with UEFI (only 64-bit supports UEFI now). So, there is no separate image for 32-bit. They still exist for 64-bit systems, and be located at an appropriate folder in http://cdimages.ubuntu.com, depending on the flavour. Right now, it seems only Lubuntu and the main Ubuntu images have them. This might because the only older Macs need it, and only these two flavours target them.

[What is different about the Mac ISO image?](https://askubuntu.com/q/37999/158442)

Comment: There are no +mac downloads for AMD64 in the GNOME releases link - is that normal?

Comment: @BilalAkil Hmm. Looks like my memory was faulty. Let me search.

Comment: @BilalAkil Looks like the Ubuntu GNOME flavour never had a +mac build. Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/q/285745/158442

Comment: Thanks for editing the answer. I'd just like to add that I've got a mid 2012 MacBook Air but I still needed the +mac version because I didn't install anything like rEFIT - I'm not sure if that's considered an "old" Mac, but yeah :P

Comment: Then you have two options: use the main image, remove `ubuntu-desktop` and install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, or use the server image, and install `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not so sure what you mean :( What do I remove from where? How can I use a particular image to install something else?

Comment: The server image lets you choose the software you want to install (so you can pick the GNOME desktop). The `ubuntu-desktop` and `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` are packages you can install and uninstall.

Comment: Fantastic, now I've got many potential pathways! Thanks a lot for your effort and hasty response :)